# Splitting text+value into two cells

Tags: excel, vba, loops, split

I have been trying to make my macro filter through the whole column, but havent been able to make a loop etc to preform the task

Text in the cells will be like

```
Name 12
(gap..)
(gap..)
Name 32
(gap..)
(gap..)
Name 2
```

etc

This code works perfect, but obviously only for A2

```
Dim avarSplit As Variant
avarSplit = Split(Range("A2").Value, "Name")
Cells(2, 1) = "Name"
Cells(2, 2) = avarSplit(1)
```

Any help/advice would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update!

ok fixing the formatting in your question has totally changed everything, try this instead

```
Sub SplitTxt()
    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then
            Cells(i, 2) = Split(Cells(i, 1), chr(32))(0)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This will place the second part of the cell string. The delimiter is <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, *Chr(32)*

Comment: Sub SplitText()
    For I = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(I, 2) = Split(Cells(I, 1), "Roosters")(1)
    Next
    End Sub

Like that? 

Because I get subscript out of range.

PS thanks for the quick reply

Comment: You may be getting a subscript out of range because there is less than 1 word in the split array. If cell is equal `Name 1` then calling `Split(...)(1)` with the `(1)` at the end results in an out of index error. `Ubound(splitedarr)` is equal to `1` as one element and `spliterarr(1)` is trying to call the 2nd element which does not exist. Simply, make sure you have at least 2 `Name` strings in a cell

Comment: I have this: from your code"

Sub SplitTxt()

    Dim i&, arr
   
    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        arr = Split(Cells(i, 1), "Name")
    Next i

End Sub

Comment: @user2742754 so what is your problem now?

Comment: Hi again. Sorry ive just re-read my question from above-  The (Gaps..) are new lines!! Sorry when I typed it out, they were set out on new lines - So never on the same cell will you see Name 12 Name 32. It is always Name 32 (new line) Name 12 etc

Comment: oh, yeah the formatting of your question totally changed the way the sub shouldve been wrote. Ive updated my answer see if this is what you are looking for

Comment: Hey - The code is not doing anything to the data now - I could upload the sample page to sendfile or something?

Comment: yes upload a screenshot please. show me what you spreadsheet looks like

Comment: @user2742754 ok, you have to use SPACE, chr(32), " " as the delimiter not a word :) I have updated the last code see if that works

Comment: So it has to be like this:           

     Cells(i, 2) = Split(Cells(i, 1), " ")(0) ?

Comment: yes, with the `(0)` if you want the word, or `(1)` for the numerical value

Comment: Still nothing happens when running it - Is there anyway to use delimiter with a word? I really want to only split the text value "Roosters"

Comment: @user2742754 typo - change `If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2)) Then` to `If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then`

Comment: Thanks again

Ive found another way to do it

 Cells.Replace What:="Sydney Roosters", Replacement:="Roosters", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :=":", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Comment: but this is totally different to what your original problem was. Try being more clear next time or other will not waste their time trying to help you.

Comment: Oppss that should be "Roosters: So now it does split it up (as per the question) - ie the first line of this example would be "Name: 12" and the it would split it. SOrry to waste your time mate. And thanks again for the help